# Facebook: search people by company name

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, search

Is there is way to search people by company name (workplace) using the Facebook API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there is way to search people by company name (workplace) using Facebook API ?

**No, there isn't any way to search people by company name.**

*But yes, you can search friends by company name by fql.*

```
select name,work_history from user where uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) and 'your company name' IN work_history.company_name
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest search you can to is:

`http://graph.facebook.com/search?q={work}&type=user`

Unfortunately, you cannot directly search for type `work` or `employment` via the Graph API.